# Len function on Float in SQLServer gives wrong length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the below query in SQL Server.

```
declare @dt float
set @dt = 1079938.05
select @dt AS Val,Convert(nvarchar(20),@dt) AS NVal, len(@dt) AS Len
```

Its output is

```
Val         NVal            Len
1079938.05  1.07994e+006    12
```

My questions are:

1. 'Val' column shows right value.
2. 'NVal' column shows strange value please explain us why it shows like this?
3. 'Len' shows length and its actual length is 10 but it shows us 12. Please explain why it shows 12 instead of 10.

Comment: Why len on a float value?

Comment: @jarlh Its my client requirement.... I don't know why but I want to give him an answer....

Comment: Any answer, or an answer he accepts, or an answer that makes sense?

Answer (score 9):

A `float` in sql server can be 4 or 8 byte. [Find details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).

`LEN()` is a function to measure the lenght of a string. So you want to measure the length of the *string representation* of the value, not the value itself.

The shown display value `1.07994e+006` is scientific notation and has 12 characters. Nothing wrong here.

Your call `Convert(nvarchar(20),@dt)` calls the `CONVERT()`-function with the defaul for `FLOAT and REAL`([Details and other formats here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)), which is *scientific* for numbers larger than 6 digits. The same happens implicitly when you call 'len(@dt)'. As the input of `LEN()` must be a string, the value is converted and then passed to the function.

What you can do:

- You might think about a conversion to `DECIMAL`...
- Another choice was first to [use `STR()`-function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx) together with `RTRIM()`.
- One more choice was [`FORMAT()`-function (SQL Server 2012+)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)
  .

Anyway you have to consider, that the **text you see is not the real value**.

Answer (score 2):

> LEN() works on [N]VARCHAR(), thus you're running into an implicit conversion from FLOAT to VARCHAR

see this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4ea2bc1-6f2f-4992-8132-f824fe4ffce0/length-of-float-values-in-ms-sql-server-gives-wrong-result?forum=transactsql

That means that `LEN` converts the value to `VARCHAR` before it actually calculates its length. That's because the length you get coincides with the length of your `NVarChar` value `1.07994e+006`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Don't use approximate data types when not forced to. A `FLOAT` is just an approximation, e.g. a simple value like 0.123 may be stored as 0.1230000000001 for instance. Use a precise type such as `DECIMAL` instead.

When converting a number to a string, you should usually specify a format as in `format(@dt, '#,###,##0.00')`. You don't do so, so it's up to the system what format to use. It uses a scientific notation 1.07994e+006 translating to 1.079940 x 10^6, which is approximately your number.

Comment: Agree, but just to mention: `FORMAT()` needs SQL Server 2012+

Comment: @Shnugo: You are right, I should have mentioned this. Also I focused so much on `float`, that I missed to say that `'len(@dt)` implicitely converts to string. So my answer renders more like a comment :-) I like your answer.

Comment: I added the hint with `Format()` to my answer just for completness... Thx and +1

Answer (score 0):

check:-
select @dt AS Val,Convert(nvarchar(20),@dt) AS NVal, len(CAST(CAST(@dt AS DECIMAL(20)) AS VARCHAR(20))) AS Len

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.