# Why Does SQL Len Function Return 7 for this Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For this TSQL query:

```
SELECT CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT) AS [Float Value]
 , LEN(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT)) AS [Length of Float Value]
 , LEN(CAST(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR)) AS [Length Cast As Varchar]
```

Result:

```
Float Value  | Length of Float Value  |  Length Cast As Varchar
14.54125     | 7                      |  7
```

Why does LEN yield 7 instead of 8 when I cast as Varchar?  Also, what implicit cast or conversion will yield 8 for LEN?

Comment: LEN(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS decimal(9,5))) yields 8.  The reason I am trying to work with FLOAT rather than Decimal(9,5) is because I don't want trailing zeroes to be counted as part of the LEN.  Example: 14.54000 (i don't want the trailing zeroes and FLOAT strips them but it also exposes the LEN issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Len function on Float in SQLServer gives wrong length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740014/len-function-on-float-in-sqlserver-gives-wrong-length) is very related and @rbr94 's answer there explains it quite well:

> LEN() works on [N]VARCHAR(), thus you're running into an implicit conversion from FLOAT to VARCHAR

It's easily proven by extending your query:

```
SELECT CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT) AS [Float Value]
 , LEN(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT)) AS [Length of Float Value]
 , LEN(CAST(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR)) AS [Length Cast As Varchar]
 , CAST(CAST(116.33 / 8 AS FLOAT) AS VARCHAR) AS [Cast As Varchar]
```

which gives

```
Float Value Length of Float Value   Length Cast As Varchar  Cast As Varchar
14.54125    7                       7                       14.5413
```

Comment: Any idea what I can do to get 8?  I see now the implicit conversion but nothing I cast or convert to is giving me the character length of "14.54125" (8).  I will update my question to include this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I am wrong but, the standard precision of float is 7 therefore here might be your problem.

You first cast the result to float which results in 7 digits.

plese view this microsoft [post](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

implicit conversion- 
see this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a4ea2bc1-6f2f-4992-8132-f824fe4ffce0/length-of-float-values-in-ms-sql-server-gives-wrong-result?forum=transactsql