# Length of a float as a string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a float type column. Most values are like 5.67 but there are some weird ones like 5.44567999999999995

How can I count how many weird ones do I have? What do I have to change in the 2nd select, to give me the result as the 3rd select?

```
declare @a as float
set @a = 5.44567999999999995
select @a
select LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ISNULL(@a, 0)))
select LEN('5.44567999999999995')
```

Comment: What is your definition of "weird"? Using float, I'd _expect_ to have some numbers like that.

Comment: What result are you currently getting for your final `SELECT`?

Comment: @Ash you mean SQL Server I guess? Thibaut meant whether it's MS SQL Server or Oracle or MySQL or whatever. You should tag the question correctly

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Perhaps you should consider decimal data type?

Comment: If these values represent money, you should not be using float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Len function on Float in SQLServer gives wrong length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740014/len-function-on-float-in-sqlserver-gives-wrong-length)

Comment: @jarlh I cannot just go ahead and modify tables on a 10 year old project. Have to work with what I have. And this column is not money.

Comment: @kutschkem I cannot just go ahead and modify tables on a 10 year old project. Have to work with what I have. And this column is not money.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to find the "weird" ones and aren't really interested in the length of the values *per se*, then you might use the `ROUND()` function instead:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
 WHERE myValue != ROUND(myValue, 2);
```

Here "2" is the number of places after the decimal - this should find values that have 3 or more decimal places.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The return of this script is 99% "normal" values, does not help :(

Comment: What do you mean by "normal"? How many decimal places does a "normal" value have?

Comment: Like I said in my original post, most of the values are like 5.67. I do not want to see those. I want to find the long weird ones, which is probably less then 100 records in a table with 15 000 records

Comment: Are you saying that the query I gave above returns values like `5.67`? See this SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4cc2f/1

Comment: @Ash, you need to specify `3` as the number of decimal places in `ROUND()` then - or however many you think is "normal": 3, 4, etc. The `2` in my answer above is the number of decimal places for a "normal" number, which I took from your example of `5.67`.