# "9.67609e+008" values getting updated in the Temporary table column when inserting data from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a temporary table and inserting data into the same. After fetching the data from the Temporary table the value for booking number column is updated as 9.67609e+008. The column has data type set to nvarchar. I should be getting the output as 967608505.

Expected output should be output as 967608505

Comment: use appropriate data type

Comment: The column might also contain alphanumeric values and hence set to nvarchar

Comment: @Sujay What value you have updated or inserted?

Comment: 967608505 this is the value which I have inserted and need the same as the output.

Comment: No one can debug code that is not provided. But if your column datatype is nvarchar, then the problem lies with the process that populates those rows in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might be the **input** datatype. Try this:

```
DECLARE @number FLOAT=967608505;

SELECT CAST(@number AS VARCHAR(100))
```

But you can avoid this by using an `INT` or `BIGINT`

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(@number AS BIGINT) AS VARCHAR(100))
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39740277/5089204) you will find some details and links, in which cases a `FLOAT` is expressed in *scientific notation* **by default**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `INT` datatype to store `int` values:

```
DECLARE @yourValue INT =  967608505
SELECT @yourValue
```

Output:

```
967608505
```

UPDATE:

To store aplhanumeric values it is possible to use `char`, `nchar` and  `nvarchar` or `varchar`. 
 Types such as `char`, `nchar` are used for very small values (e.g. 2 characters). `nvarchar` or `varchar` are used to store bigger values.

```
 DECLARE @tbl TABLE
 (
    Foo nvarchar(50),
    Bar nvarchar(50)

 )

 INSERT INTO @tbl
 (
       Foo
     , Bar 
 )
 VALUES
 (N'967608505', '967608505' )
 SELECT * FROM @tbl
```

OUTPUT:

```
Foo            Bar
967608505   967608505
```

Comment: The column contains numeric and alphanumeric values and so cannot declare the datatype as int

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your input data is actually of type `REAL` or `FLOAT`, because for those types casting/converting to `VARCHAR` uses scientific notation.

You can avoid that from happening by using the T-SQL [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) or [`STR()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql) functions:

```
DECLARE       @r REAL = 967608505    ,        @f FLOAT = 967608505
SELECT FORMAT(@r, '0') as [REAL-FMT] , FORMAT(@f, '0') as [FLOAT-FMT],
          STR(@r     ) as [REAL-STR] ,    STR(@f     ) as [FLOAT-STR]
```

Result:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| REAL-FMT  | FLOAT-FMT | REAL-STR  | FLOAT-STR |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 967608500 | 967608505 | 967608512 | 967608505 |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see the *`REAL`* value suffers from last-digit issues due to insufficient internal accuracy.

All in all we can conclude that your input variable is (or should be) *`FLOAT`*, and then it is up to you to decide which function to use.

A possible pitfall is that `STR()` produces right-aligned output, padded with spaces on the left, which can be removed by doing `LTRIM()`.

Comment: I strongly disagree... Your approach will still rely on a string method's **implicit** understanding. As long as the value **is an integer number** actually, the only clean solution is a cast to the target type and get the string form there... Btw: `FORMAT()` is known as fairly slow, while `STR()` might pad unexpectedly (try `DECLARE @n FLOAT=1.2;SELECT LEN(STR(@n))`) and both might round implicitly...